# I want to execute more than one method at a time in php

Tags: php, multithreading

Hi Please help me in executing more than one method at a time in PHP.

Below is example:

```
<?php
function writeName()
{
sleep(3);
echo "Kai Jim Refsnes";
}
function b(){
sleep(3);
echo"b";
}
b();
writeName());
?>
```

Here above program take 6 sec to execute.But I want to run my both method simultaneously so that program should execute with in 3 sec(Multi threading).

Answer (score 2):

With common PHP its not possible, because PHP is executed sequential. You may have a look at a job-server like gearman, or you may try to use forks ([pcntl_fork()](http://php.net/pcntl-fork)). It's not multi-threading, because there is no shared memory.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. But can you write program for the same so that my understanding will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but multithreading is not supported in PHP.

But you could start a PHP script which can run in the background using `exec()`. Just make sure you redirect it's output elsewhere.
That should be the closest you can get to "multithreading" without additional tools. Here's what the manual says:

> Note: If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.